# type error thrown when creating an array of object from an existing array

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

The following class has an array of integer

```
   public class customers {
     public static int ID[];

    public customers(int ID[]) {
     ID = new int[10];
     ID[0] = 00245;
     ID[1] = 76644;
    // more
}
//getters and setters
```

The subclass is defined as follow

```
      public class songs extends customers {
      //bunch of fields
```

The issue rises when within my array of objects. To create it, the following constructor was needed

```
      public songs(int ID, // bunch of fields {
       super(ID[0]);
       this.ID = ID[];
       // bunch of fields
```

Here, the super() method throws me back an error, that int[] in customers cannot be defined as a simple int.
Same goes when populating my array :

```
  arraylist.add(new songs(ID[0], ...)); // didnt paste other variables
```

ID[0] is considered a simple int and not a int[].

While I understand the error itself, I don't know what causes it nor how to make java use my array of customers within the arrayList of Object defined in songs.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: One, the array should **not** be `static` (nor should it be `public`, `protected` is probably appropriate). Two, you aren't setting `this.ID` in your code (you are ***locally*** modifying the parameter `ID = new int[10];` throw away the `ID` I was passed, create a new one that's only reachable right here). Three, class names start with a capital letter. Fix those and come back if you still have issues.

Comment: While we're on the topic of code improvements, `ID[0] = 00245;` probably doesn't do what you want it to. https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JAVA/Use+of+octal+values

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Step one and three are done; the local modifier has been removed although i fail to understand the second point; i have a setter for ID. I clearly misunderstand the concept of inheritance; what is meant by "only reachable right here"?

Comment: When you do `ID = new int[10];`... what `ID` is meant to be created? Here the `ID` created is the parameter array you passed in. **Not** the field. You have a *local* variable shadow. The parameter array named `ID`... you throw it away, and create a new `int[]`. That's a reference type. You can't modify the caller's reference. Therefor, everything you do with `ID` is erased when the constructor returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your call on `super(ID[0]);` is wrong: it calls the constructor of your `members` class, sending to it an `int` rather than an `int[]` as specified by your constructor. Moreover, I believe `this.ID = ID[];` is wrong as well: "`ID[]`" in this context doesn't represent anything.

Also, as mentioned, `static` is probably not the good approach: it means that all Objects of type "Members" will share the **same one-and-unique** attribute "`ID[]`"!

More code would help. Especially about your songs, and the "arraylist" you're talking about.

Comment: I will read further on the super() method as I am clearly misunderstanding its concept. Altering my constructor to int[] doesn't change the issue I have. I feel like i am misunderstanding what you are saying. Apologize for the lack of criticism.

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to do with the `ID[]` attribute of `members`. The call on `super(ID[0])` sends the parameter "ID[0]" to the constructor of the class that extends `songs`. See it as your `songs` constructor having it's first line being replaced by `this = new member(ID[0])`. This is wrong: your `member` class takes an **array of int** as a parameter. `ID[0]` refers to the first element in an array of `int`, which is thus an int, and not an array of int. Moreover, I don't think that you understand what `extends` does. Lastly: Capitalize the first letter of your classes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an array through subclass constructor you must first have a non-static (instance) array field in your super class, like this:

```
private int[] ids;
```

Be noticed that in java the fields are usually defined in camel case format. 
Also you have a syntax error in this line:

```
super(ID[0])
```

You are referencing the int parameter defined in songs constructor as if an array, that is not correct.